# How can I change Referential Integrity from a Unique Key Constraint to a Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, referential-integrity

(without dropping foreign keys)

I have migrated a SQL Server CE database to SQL Server 2012, however, referential integrity was enforced via unique key constraints on the surrogate `INT` identity columns.

e.g.

```
create table Table1
(
   Table1ID INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT U_000001 UNIQUE(Table1ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
   Table2ID INT NOT NULL,
   Table1ID INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY(Table1ID) REFERENCES Table1(Table1ID)
);
```

I would like to convert the unique key constraints to primary keys, for ERD diagramming and ORM reasons.

I have added the primary keys, but cannot drop the UKC, because RI of dependent columns is already 'baked into' the UKC despite the alternative PK now being available.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (Table1ID);

ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP CONSTRAINT U_000001;
```

Fails with

> Msg 3725, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The constraint 'U_000001' is being referenced by table 'Table2', foreign key constraint 'FK_T2_T1'.

So my question is, is there any way to change the RI checks on foreign keys to use the `PRIMARY KEY`, and not the UKC as is currently the case, without having to drop the foreign keys on referencing tables first?

I have prepared a small [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b08c1).

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You need to first drop the foreign key and re-recreate them pointing to the (new) PKs

Comment: Interestingly enough, SQL seems determined to use the UKC ahead of the PK even if the RI is created afterwards, e.g.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34c52

Comment: I think this is more what a_horse suggested: [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46965)

Comment: @ypercube - indeed, that's what I had feared I had to do in the original fiddle above. I guess I was hoping there was a back door hack to somehow get Sql to switch / influence the way in which it enforced the FK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to modify which unique index a foreign key constraint is "attached to" because this is supposed to be an internal implementation detail, the same way that a unique constraint uses a unique index behind the scenes to enforce the constraint.

In fact, as you saw, if you have multiple candidate indexes, the one the foreign key attaches to seems non-deterministic (it might go by index id, index width, or something else; I haven't played with it in-depth), and it cannot be specified in the DDL statement either (memory says there's a Connect item requesting that feature, though).

So in this case, at least for now, you'll need to drop both the foreign key *and* the existing unique constraint before re-establishing the relationship, to ensure your change script works correctly in all scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Jon - will generate drop scripts for the UKC and FK's and recreate the FK's.